# How to run some SQL query on RDS using AWS SSM

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds, aws-ssm

I am trying to run some queries on RDS in a private subnet. After a bit of research, turned out the SSM is the best option. Now I have some questions.

Do I need to create an ec2 instance with an SSM agent in the private subnet To run such queries?

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of your previous question, which was closed: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72411336/how-to-run-some-sql-query-on-rds-using-ssm

Comment: You need to create an EC2 instance in any subnet in the VPC, to run such queries. Why do you think SSM is the best option?

Comment: You asked me to update my question to focus on one problem only.  so, why did you vote down my question? I don't understand what I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

As @Mark B suggested in his comment, you can run your SQL queries in EC2 instance in any subnet in a VPC as long as you have properly configured your inbound and outbound rules for your subnet and security group attached to your EC2.

Now, from your question, it is not clear as why you prefer AWS SSM and what is your use-case for it. So I am assuming you are using AWS SSM to store your DB credentials.

If you just want to run SQL query from your EC2 instance, you don't need AWS SSM as such unless you have a specific use-case. You can basically run SQL query using `psql` as follows;

```
psql -h <RDS HOST> -U <DB USERNAME> -d <DATABASE NAME> -p <DB PORT> -c "select count(*) from public.your_data_table;"
```

For the above command to succeed, you need to have DB password in `PGPASSWORD` environment variable. For example;

```
export PGPASSWORD=some_password
```

Now, again, it is not clear from your question as why you are using EC2 or what is your use-case here but you can also explore running your query through Lambda function by configuring it in proper subnet and assigning it a right security group.

A piece of advice: Before posting question, read it from a person's perspective who does not have any idea what you are trying to do. We are all here to help you as long as you provide us the right context and provide enough info to start with.

Comment: How can I run psql command if my DB is in a private subnet and does not have public access?

Comment: In fact, I have created an rds instance with terraform and need to run a sql script to configure my DBS. But the DB instance is in a private subnet and my script can not get run

Comment: You can run psql command through EC2 instance. Although this EC2 instance can be in public subnet but you can configure Netowrk ACL in our public and private subnet in such a way that private subnet receives traffic only from your public subnet. Not sure how your infrastructure is configured but you might need to configure your security groups as well.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Scenario2.html#:~:text=of%20your%20VPC.-,Recommended%20network%20ACL%20rules%20for%20a%20VPC%20with%20public%20and%20private%20subnets%20(NAT),-For%20this%20scenario